# How can I put nodes to the outliers in my boxplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes, boxplot, axis

I finally managed it to get the boxplot I wanted, but now I have no idea how to label my outliers. Does somebody have a solution?

And I also want to change the labeling of the y-axis from .5 steps to .2 steps. How can I do that?

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}\begin{figure}
\begin{document}
    \caption{Differnces between votings of external and internal auditors}
    \label{fig:Boxplot}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}

      \begin{axis}
        [ylabel =
            {$|\overline{x}\textsubscript{item}_i(internal)-\overline{x}\textsubscript{item}_i(external)|$ },
        boxplot/draw direction=y,
        xtick={1},
        xticklabels={Differences},
        x tick label style={font=\footnotesize, text width=1cm, align=center}
        ]
        \addplot+
        [mark = x, mark options = {grey},
        boxplot prepared={
        lower whisker=  0.007834,
        lower quartile= 0.1547,
        median=         0.257,
        average=        0.3763,
        upper quartile= 0.4913,
        upper whisker=  0.8585
        }, color = blue
        ]
       coordinates{(0,1.035) (0,1.194)(0,1.491)}
        node[right] at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{average}, .5),
        node[right] at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{1.035}, .5)
        {\boxplotvalue{average}}
        ;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. For the last part, `ytick distance=0.2`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly what you're after, you can perhaps use `nodes near coords`. Did you want the value printed next to the outliers, or something else?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
        ylabel =
            {$|\overline{x}_{\text{item}i} (\text{internal})-\overline{x}_{\text{item}i} (\text{external})|$ },
        boxplot/draw direction=y,
        xtick={1},
        xticklabels={Differences},
        x tick label style={
           font=\footnotesize,
           text width=1cm,
           align=center
        },
        % set distance between yticks
        ytick distance=0.2
        ]
        \addplot+
        [mark = x, mark options = {mark color=grey},
        boxplot prepared={
        lower whisker=  0.007834,
        lower quartile= 0.1547,
        median=         0.257,
        average=        0.3763,
        upper quartile= 0.4913,
        upper whisker=  0.8585
        }, color = blue,
        % activate nodes near coords -- makes a node with the meta value next to the point
        nodes near coords,
        % put the node right of the point
        nodes near coords align=right,
        ]
       coordinates{
           (0,1.035) 
           (0,1.194) 
           (0,1.491) 
       }
      node[right] at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{average}, .5) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{average}}}
      ;

      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is it possible to name the outliers with character values like "outlier"?

Comment: @Bolle `nodes near coords=outlier` instead of just `nodes near coords` in the `axis` options, if you want the same text for all of them.